# Como gravar dados arquivo CSV sem apagar os dados já existentes

Tags: python

Preciso salvar dados em arquivo CSV sem que ele apague os dados já existentes no arquivo, apenas crie uma nova linha com os dados informados

```
 material=str(input('Informe o material: '))

 mod_elasticidade=float(input('Informe o modulo de elasticidade do material:'))

 tensao_escoamento=float(input('Informe a tensao de escoamento do material:'))

 historico = open("historico.csv","w")

 linha=str(material)+";"+str(mod_elasticidade)+";"+str(tensao_escoamento)

 historico.write(linha)

 historico.close()
```

Answer (score 4):

Basta trocar o `w` por `a+`, assim:

```
historico = open("historico.csv", "a+")

linha=str(material)+";"+str(mod_elasticidade)+";"+str(tensao_escoamento)

historico.write(linha)

historico.close()
```

ps: use o `with`, assim quando o bloco terminar ele fecha o arquivo sozinho, assim:

```
material = str(input('Informe o material: '))

mod_elasticidade = float(input('Informe o modulo de elasticidade do material:'))

tensao_escoamento = float(input('Informe a tensao de escoamento do material:'))

linha = str(material)+";"+str(mod_elasticidade)+";"+str(tensao_escoamento)

with open("historico.csv", "a+") as historico:
    historico.write(linha)
```

Comment: Troquei o "w" por "a+" não apaga as dados ja existentes no arquivo, porem ele grava as novas informações na mesma linha dos dados existentes, preciso que grava os dados na próxima linha em branco do arquivo e não na mesma linha

Comment: @FabioDalZotto mas era para o `a+` fazer isso, quem grava nas linhas existentes é o `a` sem o sinal de `+`, o sinal de mais move o ponteiro para o final, a não ser que seja um BUG, você deve ter feito algo a mais no seu script que falhou nisto, simplesmente isso não era para ocorrer.